# Xcode header error - namespace '_STL' does not enclose namespace '_Rep'

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm currently developing on Xcode, when I tried to include string

```
#include <string>
```

everything is fine, but when I include CryptoPP header which includes `<string>`

```
#include "integer.h" //integer.h have #include <string> in it
```

I got the following errors while compiling

```
bits/basic_string.tcc:63:11: Cannot define or redeclare '_S_max_size' here because     namespace '_STL' does not enclose namespace '_Rep'
bits/basic_string.tcc:63:28: Use of undeclared identifier 'npos'; did you mean 'fpos'?
bits/basic_string.tcc:63:28: Use of class template fpos requires template arguments
bits/basic_string.tcc:63:33: Expected ')'
bits/basic_string.tcc:68:11: Cannot define or redeclare '_S_terminal' here because namespace '_STL' does not enclose namespace '_Rep'
bits/basic_string.tcc:72:44: Cannot define or redeclare 'npos' here because namespace '_STL' does not enclose namespace 'basic_string'
bits/basic_string.tcc:99:2: Unknown type name 'size_type'; did you mean 'size_t'?
bits/basic_string.tcc:100:9: Use of undeclared identifier '__beg'
bits/basic_string.tcc:100:9: Use of undeclared identifier '__end'
bits/basic_string.tcc:100:9: Use of undeclared identifier '_Rep'
```

and so on...

Is this some error in system headers or the error is in the compiler? I'm using Apple LLVM 4.2 (and I need to use it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to include the internal headers. If you want to get the declarations needed for `std::basic_string` include `<string>`.

Comment: Actually its the CryptoPP code and it includes like this several times in code.

Comment: @bartimar: Just because something is used in a library it is right! I downloaded CryptoPP-5.6.2 and it doesn't include any such header. The internal standard library headers are the sole business of the standard library.

Comment: Cryptopp integer -> cryptlib -> stdcpp -> string -> basic_string.tcc (arrow means include)

Comment: @bartimar: This is an indirect include via `<string>`. Are you saying you have problems compiling cryptopp which include `<string>` with the compiler complaining in `<bits/basic_string.tpp>`? ... or are you explicitly including `<bits/basic_string.tpp>` because it happens to be included eventually somewhere else?

Comment: I have problems compiling cryptopp which include <string>. But I can compile the whole cryptopp project and make a static lib. But when I include the static lib in other project and use some cryptopp header i got this errors (cause of string)

Comment: @bartimar: Check if your project defines `_STL`. It seems something is stepping on names used by (and reserved for) the standard C++ library.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35898/discussion-between-dietmar-kuhl-and-bartimar)